# Matching the first and last charcters in a fasta file

Tags: r, regex, fasta

I have a fasta sequences like following:

```
fasta_sequences
    seq1_1
    "MTFJKASDKASWQHBFDDFAHJKLDPAL"
    seq1_2
    "GTRFKJDAIUETZUQOIHHASJKKJHPAL"
    seq1_3
    "MTFJHAZOQIIREUUBSDFHGTRF"
    seq2_1
    "JUZGFNBGTFCKAJDASEJIJAS"
    seq2_1
    "MTFHJHJASBBCMASDOEQSDPAL"
    seq2_3
    "RTZIIASDPLKLKLKLLJHGATRF"
    seq3_1
    "HMTFLKBNCYXBASHDGWPQWKOP"
    seq3_2
    "MTFJKASDJLKIOOIEOPWEIOKOP"
```

I would like to retain only those sequences which starts with MTF and ends with either KOP or TRF or PAL. At the end it should be like

```
    seq1_1
    "MTFJKASDKASWQHBFDDFAHJKLDPAL"
    seq1_3
    "MTFJHAZOQIIREUUBSDFHGTRF"
    seq2_1
    "MTFHJHJASBBCMASDOEQSDPAL"
    seq3_2
    "MTFJKASDJLKIOOIEOPWEIOKOP"
```

I tried the following code in R but it gave me which contains nothing

```
new_fasta=grep("^MTF.*(PAL|TRF|KOP)$")
```

Could anyone help how to get the desired output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try as `^(MTF.*(KOP|TRF|PAL))$`

Comment: Nitpick: those are not fasta sequences. That said, please [edit] your question and tell us how those sequences are stored. Ideally, give us the code you use to create the R variables that stores them so we can test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to go i guess;

For every element in fasta_sequences; (if fasta_sequences is a vector containing the sequences)

```
newseq = list()
it=1
for (i in fasta_sequences){
  # i is seq1_1, seq1_2 etc.
  a=substr(i,1,3)
  if (a=="MTF"){
  x=substr(i,(nchar(i)-2),nchar(i))

  if ( x=="PAL" | x=="KOP" | x=="TRF"){
    newseq[it]=i
    it=it+1
  }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
new_fasta=grep("^MTF.*(PAL|TRF|KOP)$",fasta_sequences,perl=True)


                                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

Add `perl=True` option.

Comment: the above command gives me only the numbers but not the sequences and its name

Comment: @Dino what numbers...also you have to given any `string` to grep.

Comment: It shows the total number of entries that been matched with the pattern.

Comment: @Dino then you need to use `gsub("(MTF.*(?:PAL|TRF|KOP))","\\1",fasta_sequence,perl=TRUE)`